# From a vector of 1 and 0, how to keep only the ones before the first 0?

Tags: r

To parse a text file, I want to extract all numeric lines after a certain character string appears. I have managed to extract the text. Now selecting only numeric lines that appear after this text boils down to this little problem. From a vector of 0 and 1, I want to keep only the ones before the first 0.

```
a <- c(1,0,1)
b <- c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
```

The function f should return:

```
f(a)
c(1,0,0)
f(b)
c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

I tried using

```
which.min(a)
[1] 2
which.min(b)
[1] 5
```

Or

```
cumsum(!a)==0
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
cumsum(!b)==0
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I guess there is a simple solution but I'm probably too sleepy this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `cummin` function

```
cummin(a)
#[1] 1 0 0

cummin(b)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ,

```
a[which(a == 0):length(a)] <- 0
#a
#[1] 1 0 0
```

and

```
b[which(b == 0):length(b)] <- 0

#b
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Although, this gives the desired output. However, for `b` this gives a warning message :

```
Warning message:
In which(b == 0):length(b) :
numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

As result for `which(b==0)` is `#[1]  5  9 10`

---

Alternatively, you can

```
a[which.min(a):length(a)] <- 0
b[which.min(b):length(b)]  <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks I was coming to a much more verbose solution `c(b[c(1:which.min(b))],rep(0,length(b)-which.min(b)))`.